# Passive structure

Tags: passive-voice

Today, while I was doing my grammar exercises I found an unusual answer in the answer key . I am working on passive structure. In one of the exercises the books says that the correct answer is:

> *the boat hit a rock and **sank** quickly.*

but i think the correct answer is:

> *the boat hit a rock and **was sunk** quickly.*

because I think  it can't sink by itself! I mean, if I say " I sank something" it means **I did** it in the past! In this case this sentences mean the boat sank another thing!

What do you think ?

The book I referred to: *Grammar in Use* (Raymond Murphy-third edition)

Comment: We can't tell you if the answer is correct without seeing the question....

Comment: Many verbs (like _sink_) can be used either intransitively (_The ship sank_) or transitively, with a causative sense (_The iceberg sank the ship_). If a transitive sentence with _sink_ gets passivized (_The ship was sunk_), it has the same meaning as the intransitive sentence, but implies that the sinking was caused by something outside the ship.

Answer (score 2):

> because I think it can't sink by itself

When you think that, it's always a good idea to check a dictionary.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sink) tells us this about *sink*:

> intransitive verb
>   1
>   a :  to go to the bottom :  submerge
>   [...]
>   transitive verb
>   1
>   a :  to cause to sink

As you can see, the verb can be intransitive, meaning that ships *can* sink by themselves. There is nothing wrong with "the ship sank".

At the same time, it *can* be used transitively, in the way you considered. Someone can sink a ship, and a ship can be sunk (by someone).

Comment: Well, you can speak *as though* ships can sink by themselves, but that doesn't mean they actually *can*.  Grammar is not physics.

Comment: @GregLee Why can't ships sink by themselves?

Comment: @phoog, I don't have a position on whether ships can sink by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are both possible.

Things do sink, though. They sink themselves. The sun sinks itself down below the horizon. People sink drinks down themselves.

And, of course, they get sunk - by the things doing the sinking, and the things causing the sinking, like the rocks, or the accident, causing the sinking of the ship.

Comment: Mentioning a contrived reflexive form is a bit confusing. If a ship sinks, it does _not_ sink itself. It just sinks.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct, but they both use a different form of the verb *to sink*.

The two forms are:

1. Transitive (= with object)

   > Something/someone sinks something/someone else.
2. Intransitive (= without object)

   > Something/someone sinks.

I hope that helped!